# SHA256 хеш функция

Tags: sha

Здравствуйте! Есть 2 хеша:
1) `8032d315b75b7ed85f8932a2954dcb47bb7b0e2ca95c5c5de5e9518cbfa9ef1e`

2) `a3d83d5db9abd3631a674d6ab0da9706c331c2bfa1b408047101f4c2cb977dd2` — это `sha256(8032d315b75b7ed85f8932a2954dcb47bb7b0e2ca95c5c5de5e9518cbfa9ef1e)`

Сколько должно перебрать комбинаций, если хешировать `a3d83d5db9abd3631a674d6ab0da9706c331c2bfa1b408047101f4c2cb977dd2`  сам в себе постоянно?  10<sup>77</sup> комбинаций?

И можно ли как-то пропустить большое количество комбинаций, чтобы при хешировании `a3d83d5db9abd3631a674d6ab0da9706c331c2bfa1b408047101f4c2cb977dd2` я смог повторилучить этот же хеш и хеш, с которого этот будет получён?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24623/cycles-in-sha256

Comment: Вопрос по прежнему остался.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача является частным случаем нахождения **коллизии SHA-256**.

#### Но SHA-256 *на сегодняшний день* считается криптостойким хэшем.

Из этого следуют ответы на все ваши вопросы:

> Сколько должно перебрать комбинаций

Все. Ничего быстрее полного перебора для криптостойких хэшей нет.

> можно ли как-то пропустить большое количество комбинаций

Нет, нельзя.

---

Как только ответы на вышеописанные вопросы изменятся, от SHA-256 немедленно начнут отказываться, как сейчас отказываются от SHA-1 в SSL-сертификатах. Даже несмотря на то, что **одна** атака на SHA-1 требует гигантского количества ресурсов.